# Regex to retrieve token from page source

Tags: regex

What is the regex to retrieve the value of the `"token"` attribute from the following json fragment?

> 259,"possible_flags":["recommending","looking-for"],"id":297,"organisations":[],"showWarning":false,"token":"bf311e7a1a4e49846c0fb836934e7685610829d0","intention":"neighbourhood-nearby"...

I want to match `bf311e7a1a4e49846c0fb836934e7685610829d0`.

Comment: probably because you didn't show what you tried to solve the problem; nor mention which language you're using; nor mention the situation!

Comment: I'm just after a piece of regex, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the full text including "token":"___"

`("token":"[A-z0-9]*")`

This will give you just the token:

`"token":("[A-z0-9]*")`

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match the the token value:

```
(?<="token":")[^"]*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/WtSiJ4mhLh).

It uses a look behind as the starting anchor, then matches the non-quote chars that follow.

Note that the *whole* match is your target (no need for capturing or extracting groups).